# Custom WordPress template loads only header & footer

Tags: php, css, wordpress, header, footer

I have a weird problem. I'm trying to make custom template for WordPress.
index.php works perfectly fine - everything what should load, loads with no problems.

index.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?> 
<?php if ( is_home() &&function_exists('get_template_part')) get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

But when I create a new page, like promotions.php and put custom code, It does not show up on the page. I can see only header & footer section. It looks like I didn't put any code at all.

Comment: You are using condition is_home() so data will show only on home page

Comment: Share your code that you added in custom template.

Comment: So I should hard code everything from content into index.php (I want the 'content' to show up only at the main site). And then I can code the rest of the pages?

Comment: you are using the same code present in the index.php ?

Comment: In subpages like promotions I have only HTML code, like <div class="text">blablabla</div>

Comment: I noticed that I can put totally random adress like (mywebsite)/nonesense.nonsense and it still loads the site (header & footer)

Answer (score 0):

You can make custom page templates like so

```
<?php
 /**
   * Template name: custom-name
   */

  get_header();
  if (is_home()) {
    get_template_part('content', get_post_format());
  }
   get_footer(); ?>
```

And then inside WordPress you can edit the page. On the right side below publish you can see default template. Choose your template and hit save.

**Edit:**

See the image below for further instructions.

[image]

Comment: I think I messed up hard. When I'm logged in the website looks like a mess. Here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/ho6OLv5.png but when I go not logged in http://i.imgur.com/VTU4UO2.png also, where shall I put this code you mentioned above?

Comment: @AdamsRX You create a new file called "promotions.php" and put my code in it. Then see the image in my previous answer for further instructions.

Comment: Okay, I figured this out BUT I want to make custom subsite from a scratch (open notepad++ >> start coding >> save as promo.php >> upload ) is it even possible? I removed all the blog features from the theme.My website uses no blog features at all so far. (I want to add a small section with recent posts on the bottom of the page). The rest of the page should be a custom HTML. And the recent news section (with posts) should only appear on the main site.

Comment: And still... applying templae ends with empty page with header&footer displayed.

Comment: I don't know anymore.. you can try to give me acces so I can take a look to the problem..

Answer (score 0):

Use flush_rewrite_rules() function one time in functions.php.
All should works after that.